# How to transform a list to string conditioned by the type of the list element

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of strings which I want to transform to a single string.

The list contains integers which I don't want to separate them with space.

For example I have the list:

```
lst = ['This', 'house', 'has', 1, 2, 'rooms']
```

They way I am using to make a string is:

```
' '.join([str(elem) for elem in lst])
```

Which of course results in:  'This house has 1 2 rooms'

The intention is to get:  'This house has 12 rooms'

I am not sure how to condition the *join* statement from above based on the type of the element of the list in order to have the space if it is an a string and an empty string if it is an int.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: *Don't separate* the digits in the first place?

Comment: @super rain thank you for the suggestion. However, I can't change the input, such a list is what I receive.

Comment: Why do you receive it like that?

Comment: This is how the sentence was separated. I can't change that operation so I have to fix its result.

Comment: Or you could report it as a bug.

Comment: Actually I did but it was decided that this how I should receive the transcription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be over-engineered solution, but here it is:

```
' '.join(filter(lambda y: (y != ''), ((''.join([str(' '+x+' ') if type(x) is str else str(x) for x in lst])).strip().split(' '))))
```

Explaination:

1. Check the type of elem, if str then add one space before and one after and use strip() to strip leading and ending spaces
2. This will give you `'This  house  has 12 rooms'`
3. As you can see, there are some elements with two space, so we split the list by spaces. We get `['This', '', 'house', '', 'has', '12', 'rooms']`
4. we filter out the empty spaces from the list. We would get this list by this filter. `['This', 'house', 'has', '12', 'rooms']`
5. We join back the list by single whitespace.

It will give below output:

```
'This house has 12 rooms'
```

Answer (score 2):

Grouping with `itertools`:

```
>>> ' '.join(('' if t is int else ' ').join(map(str, g))
             for t, g in groupby(lst, type))
'This house has 12 rooms'
```

Comment: Thank you @superb rain this also works! I will have to study about itertools capabilities better

Answer (score 1):

You could first join the strings and then remove spaces between digits:

```
lst = ['This', 'house', 'has', 1, 2, 'rooms']
s = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in lst])
re.sub(r"(?<=\d) (?=\d)", "", s)
```

It gives:

```
'This house has 12 rooms'
```

Comment: I was also trying to do it with a regular expression but I just could not syntax it

Comment: If possible could you elaborate/confirm my understanding on the explanation of the regular expression ? The sub method does first parameter you searches for a pattern in the string s where when you find it you replace with an empty string. Now, the regular expression itself  (pattern) is:  ?= identifies whether the next element is digit. From the documentation I could not understand  ?<=\d. Can you explain it maybe it a few words ?

Comment: `(?=\d)`  is lookahead - it checks if the next character is a digit. In turn `(?<=\d)` is lookbehind, which checks if the previous character is a digit. Altogether  `(?<=\d) (?=\d)` will match a space character if there are digits on both its sides. `re.sub` replaces each such space character with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`"".join(" " + elem + " " if isinstance(elem, str) else str(elem) for elem in list).replace("  ", " ").strip()`